# Python: how to copy between lists using lists, e.g. list1[index1] = list2[index2]

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Say we have two lists of values, `list1` and `list2`, and tow lists of indices, `index1` and `index2`. How do we copy elements with position `index2` in `list2` to elements with position `index1` in `list1`. In Matlab, for example, we can simply write `list1[index1] = list2[index2]`, but strangely this does not seem to work in Python. Also, how do we do this if `index1` and/or `index2` is a list of booleans?

For example, say `list1 = ['a','b','c','d','e']` and `list2 = ['A','B','C','D','E']` and `index1 = [0,1,3]` and `index2 = [1,2,4]` with the result of `list1[index1] = list2[index2]` being `list1: ['B','C','c','E','e']`.

In the case of boolean, the same output should be achived with `index1 = [True,True,False,True,False]` and `index2 = [False,True,True,False,True]`.

**PS: It is clear how to do this with a `for` loop. I am looking for a more "pythonic" way, e.g. list comprehension. Thank you**

**PPS: After some experimentation, I defined a class `MyList` which inhereted from class Python's `list` and modified `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` to accept lists of integers or booleans. The class definition is given in my post here [How to extend list class to accept lists for indecies in Python, e.g. to use list1[list2] = list3[list4]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57555999/how-to-extend-list-class-to-accept-lists-for-indecies-in-python-e-g-to-use-lis)**

Comment: just make sure both lists are of the same length (or the target list is longer) - you cannont `i[8] = 42` for an `i = [0,1]` because there is no 8th element to replace. Also be aware of the mutable nature of lists if you copy over refereces from a list that has list references inside. You will not create distinct new lists in that case

Comment: If index1 and/or index2 is a list of booleans, which element in `list2` do you identify to copy to `list1`?

Comment: @Austin Of course I tried. I get an error "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list"

Comment: Hmm, I don't see `index1` and `index2` are lists. Please give sample inputs to avoid confusions.

Comment: @Austin `list1[index1]` should subset `n` elements and `list2[index2]` should also subset `n` elements and so we assign values from the later subset to the former subset

Comment: @SuvenPandey Boollean just tels which elements of the list to subset.

Comment: @SuvenPandey I mean `True` values in `index1` and `index2` determine which elements to subset from `list1` and `list2` respectively and then we simply assign elements from one subset to another, i.e. `subset1 = subset2`.

Comment: Please edit your question to include possible input with expected output and lets not extend comment conversation.

Comment: My previous answer works if index1 and index2 have integers. Since, I dont know how to make it work with boolean values I'll be deleting my answer. The only way I know if to check if value of index1 is boolean or not and implement if-else statement for two cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple for-loop with `enumerate`:

```
list1 = ['a','b','c','d','e']
list2 = ['A','B','C','D','E']
index1 = [0,1,3]
index2 = [1,2,4]

for i, val in enumerate(index1):
    list1[val] = list2[index2[i]]

print(list1)
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> ['B', 'C', 'c', 'E', 'e']
> ```

Or alternatively with `zip`:

```
list1 = ['a','b','c','d','e']
list2 = ['A','B','C','D','E']
index1 = [0,1,3]
index2 = [1,2,4]

for a, b in zip(index1, index2):
    list1[a] = list2[b]

print(list1)
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> ['B', 'C', 'c', 'E', 'e']
> ```

As far as I can see, the boolean case is a completely different one, and should be asked in a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `zip` and combine the elements of the two index lists.

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
list2 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
index1 = [0, 1, 3]
index2 = [1, 2, 4]

for i1, i2 in zip(index_1, index_2):
    list1[i1] = list2[i2]

print(list1)
```

Comment: Does this handle index1 index2 can be boolean case?

Comment: No, it does not. With booleans you have a list with a different meaning.

Answer (score -2):

```
list1 = ['a','b','c','d','e']
list2 = ['A','B','C','D','E']
index1 = [0,1,3]
index2 = [1,2,4]
x=0
for i in index1:
    list1[i] = list2[index2[x]]
    x+=1
print(list1)
```