# How to extend list class to accept lists for indecies in Python, e.g. to use list1[list2] = list3[list4]

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to extend the list class in Python so that it can accept lists of integers and booleans as indices.

I am new to python and while I have some, albeit limited, experience with object-oriented languages, I have only created classes "from scratch" and it's not clear to me how the square brackets `[]` method (is it method?) can be captured.

Do I need to modify methods (?) `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` in my inherited class to check for the type of object that has been passed in and then perform appropriate operations?

I am have tried the following definition of a class `MyList` but it doesn't work.

```
class MyList(list):

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if type(index) is list:
            for i in index:
                return self[i]
        else:
            return self[index] 

    def __setitem__(self, index, item):
        if type(index) is list:
            for i,v in zip(index,item):
               self[i] = v
        else:
            self[i] = item
```

If input indices are lists of integers then given, for example,

```
list1=['a','b','c','d','e']
list2=['A','B','C','D','E']
index1=[0,1,3]
index2=[1,2,4]
```

I would like to be able to use an expression

```
list1[index1] = list2[index2]
```

to result in

```
list1 : ['B','C','c','E','e']
```

If input indices are lists of boolean then the same output should be achieved with

```
index1=[True,True,False,True,False]
index2=[False,True,True,False,True]
```

**Add 1**

Apparently, one needs to call the method of the parent class directly, so I changed the definition of `__getitem__` to

```
   def __getitem__(self, index):
        if type(index) is list:
            res = [None]*len(index)
            for i,v in enumerate(index):
                res[i] = list.__getitem__(self, v)
            return res
        else:
            return list.__getitem__(self, index)
```

and this seems to have worked. Need to work on `__setitem__` and do further tests.

**Add 2**

I have now modified `__setitem__` as

```
    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        if type(index) is list:
            for i,v in zip(index, value):
                list.__setitem__(self,i,v)
        else:
            list.__setitem__(self,index,value)
```

and this also seems to work. Will next extend the definitions to accept boolean lists.

**Add 3**

I have now added boolean lists to definitions and the full class is given by

```
class MyList(list):

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if type(index) is list:
            if type(index[0]) is bool:
                index = [i for i,v in enumerate(index) if v]
                return self[index]
            elif type(index[0]) is int:
                res = [None]*len(index)
                for i,v in enumerate(index):
                    res[i] = list.__getitem__(self, v)
                return res
        else:
            return list.__getitem__(self, index)

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        if type(index) is list:
            if type(index[0]) is bool:
                index = [i for i,v in enumerate(index) if v]
                self[index] = value
            elif type(index[0]) is int:
                for i,v in zip(index, value):
                    list.__setitem__(self,i,v)
        else:
            list.__setitem__(self,index,value)
```

which seems to produce desired results.

Comment: The first one would work if you did not return from inside the loop

Comment: for completeness sake, you could move your last part to an answer and accept it

Comment: This functionality is supported by arrays in the `numpy` library.

Answer (score 0):

Following the suggestion from @Tomerikoo in the comments, I am adding my last part here as an answer.

```
class MyList(list):

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if type(index) is list:
            if type(index[0]) is bool:
                index = [i for i,v in enumerate(index) if v]
                return self[index]
            elif type(index[0]) is int:
                res = [None]*len(index)
                for i,v in enumerate(index):
                    res[i] = list.__getitem__(self, v)
                return res
        else:
            return list.__getitem__(self, index)

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        if type(index) is list:
            if type(index[0]) is bool:
                index = [i for i,v in enumerate(index) if v]
                self[index] = value
            elif type(index[0]) is int:
                for i,v in zip(index, value):
                    list.__setitem__(self,i,v)
        else:
            list.__setitem__(self,index,value)
```

There might be some issues with the above that I am not aware of, so will wait for other responses before accepting it. I suppose I should add some code that throws an error if `index` is neither `int` or `bool`.